# VBA to autohide and unhide columns based on cell values in range. BUt need to add an extra condition on top

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that currently auto hides or unhides based on a certain range of cells. Currently, it loops through every time a cell is changed and I get the blue wheel for 5-10 seconds every time. I would like it pull from a different sheet based on if a value changes then run the code, if the value in specific cell doesn't change then the code doesn't run.

So essentially based on code below. Id like the code to look at the specific cell on sheet 1, cell L19 and if that number changes, then the code below will auto kick in, if the sheet 1 L19 cell doesn't change the code below doesn't run.

Currently my code is this:

```
Sub Worksheet_Selectionchange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r1 As Range
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set ws = Sheet6
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect "Password"
    For Each r1 In ws.Range("G19:AD19")
        If r1.Value = "" Then
            r1.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Else
            r1.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next r1
   ActiveSheet.Protect "Password"
   End Sub
```

Comment: change to worksheet_change event instead and test if the target is L19

Comment: Scott, Thanks for the reply. Do I need to add extra coding to add L19 as the target? I changed to worksheet_change and it didn't update anything.

Comment: You have to test if the target is L19, If so do your code.  If not then do nothing.

Comment: Hi Scott, I am relatively new to the VBA stuff. I am not really following the test the target. Would you be able to show me? Thank you so much for your quick responses